# Retrieve JSON Object and populate array Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I have a json object of this structure:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "seat_no": 6
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "seat_no": 27
    }
]
```

The main challenge is that I need to get the seat_no and add that to an int array which I will be using later on:

```
func getReserved() -> [Int] {
  var reservedSeatsJSON : JSON = JSON()
  var seats = Int()
  var reservedSeats = [Int]()

  for item in reservedSeatsJSON.array! {
     seats = item["seat_no"].int!
     reservedSeats.append(seats)
     self.reservedSeatsLabel.text = "Reserved(\(reservedSeatsJSON.array!.count))"
  }
  return reservedSeats      
}
```

Each time I run this, the reservedSeats returns empty. The main idea here is that I need to populate an int array in a for loop and return the populated array outside the for loop

Comment: After your loop finishes, how come your `reservedSeats` array is empty?

Comment: That is the mystery I am trying to solve. Maybe I'm doing something wrong or there is some thing wrong with the logic

Comment: Add a statement printing out `seats` in the loop. I think you'll be surprised by the output.

Comment: I edited the code. The print statement does produce 6, 27 but the reservedSeats is still []

Comment: There's no print statement in the code you posted. Where are you seeing 6 and 27 being printed?

Answer (score 1):

First check is `reservedSeatsJSON` json contains actual JSON?

if it contains actual `JSON` then do as like below. short and simple way.

```
func getReserved() -> [Int] {
     var reservedSeatsJSON : JSON = JSON()
     self.reservedSeatsLabel.text = "Reserved(\(reservedSeatsJSON.array.count))" 

     return reservedSeatsJSON.arrayValue.map { $0["seat_no"].intValue }
}
```

Comment: The format of the JSON I receive is exactly as it is in my question. So I need to access the seat_no in another function. I tried your solution but it returns an empty array.

Comment: @user1514567 did you find any solution?

Comment: is this sample json in your array is complete or partial?